# Are the integrals divergent or convergent?

Tags: calculus

I want to determine if the following integrals converge or diverge.

1. $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x^5+1}}dx.$
2. $\int_{0}^\infty \sin\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$.
3. $\int_{\sqrt{2}}^2 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-2}}dx.$
4. $\int_{0}^1 \frac{\ln{x}}{x}dx.$

---

**(1):** Here I can raise the integrand to the third power and use that $$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x^5+1}}\leq\int_{0}^\infty\frac{x^{3/2}}{x^5+1},$$

Clearly the RHS is convergent since the denominator grow faster than the numerator. Is this correct reasoning?

**(2):** Just by looking at it I can say that as $x\rightarrow \infty$ then the argument for $\sin$ approaches $0$, so the entire function approaches 0, thus the integral is convergent. Same question as the above, is this reasoning correct? And how can one show this analytically?

**(3):** Having trouble with this one. Clearly the function is not defined at $x=\sqrt{2}$, should I instead then be looking at $$-\lim_{n\rightarrow \sqrt{2}}\int_{2}^{n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-2}}?$$

**(4):** This one seemed simple at first glance. I used the function $\ln(x)$ for comparison. $$\int_{0}^1\frac{\ln{x}}{x}dx\le \int_{0}^1 \ln{x}dx,$$

I know that the right integral is convergent since its value is $-1$, but why is the left integral divergent?

Comment: One question, one post. Please and thank you.

Comment: This is a question from an old exam in my school, it IS one question on the exam.

Comment: Then it has too many parts. Please narrow the 'question' down to a single question. This will improve the chances of your questions being answered and kept open.

Comment: the first integral is convergent.

Comment: the second one is also convergent

Comment: the third one is also convergent and has the value $$2\,{\it arctanh} \left( \sqrt {2}-1 \right) $$

Comment: For the first one, if something is less than $1$ (and positive) then raising it to the third power makes it smaller. So that argument doesn't hold.

Comment: So anyone answering the second and fourth, or the first and second, or all four, and more answers the question?  This is far too broad a question (four separate questions in all) which makes answering *them* carefully requires too many answers, or too much space.

Comment: Only the fourth one  clearly diverges and the oder clearly converge see the prove below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **For 2. we know that** $|\sin x| \le |x|$

hence $$ |\sin\frac{1}{x^2+1}|\le \frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

So $$\left|\int_0^\infty\sin\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx\right|\le \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx \quad\text{converges}$$

- **For 4. We have that**  $(\ln x)'=\frac1x$

$$\int_{0}^{1}{ f\left(x\right) f'\left(x\right) dx} = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x}dx =\lim_{a\to 0} \frac12[\ln^2 x]^1_a =\lim_{a\to 0} \frac12 \ln^2 a =+\infty$$
so $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x}  dx = \infty.$$

- **For3. we have that** $$x^2-2 =(x-\sqrt 2)(x+\sqrt 2)\sim x-\sqrt 2\text{ as }x\to \sqrt 2$$ Then $$\int_{\sqrt{2}}^2 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-2}}. \sim \int_{\sqrt{2}}^2 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x-\sqrt2}}dx = \int^{2-\sqrt{2}}_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt u}du\quad\text{converges} .$$
- **For 1. it converges since**

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x^5+1}}\sim \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^{5/3}} = \frac{1}{x^{7/6}}~~as ~~x\to \infty$$
but $7/6>1$ so $$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^{7/6}}dx~~~\text{converges}$$
this implies that
 $$\int_1^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x^5+1}} dx~~~\text{converges}$$
also 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x^5+1}} = 0~$$

so $$\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x^5+1}} dx~~~\text{converges}$$

Answer (score 1):

2)

Just because $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ does not mean that the improper integral $\displaystyle \int_a^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ converges.
The classic example is the reciprocal function. Clearly $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{x}=0$. However, the integral $$\int_1^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}\,dx=\lim_{b\to\infty} \ln(b)$$ diverges.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: For 2), OP asked is his reasoning was correct. I was answering that question.

Comment: But anyway that was simpliest one which claerly convergs see above